# T-SQL dates comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Is a result set of the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Date >= '20130101'
```

equals to result set of the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Date = '20130101'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Date > '20130101'
```

?
`Date` is `DATETIME` field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the result YES but on the performance NO.

There may have a performance issue. The first one only scans the table once while the second one scans twice because of `UNION`. (*one `SELECT` statement is more faster than two combine select statement*)

So I'd rather go on the first one.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, of course I meant `WHERE Date >= '20130101'`. My bad

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not going to use the second way. The reason of my question is that I performed a query with `WHERE Date > '20130101'`. Now I'm wondering what if I perform query with `WHERE Date = '20130101'`, will the result sets match or not